# How Android Product Flavors and Configuration help to maintain and support single code base to distribute multiple client

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-productflavors, code-maintainability

I have a requirement Android Product Flavors and Configuration help to maintain and support single code base to distribute multiple clients. 
 I referred few links, It gives a basic idea. My question is actually Am I'm going correct direction. I very new to this kind scenario.

eg:
Product name: MohanApp
client 1: Cartoon,
client 2: Disney,
client 3: Pogo,

```
flavorDimensions "app", "server"
    productFlavors {
        cartoon {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId 'com.cc.whitelabel.cartoon'
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@drawable/cartoon_network"
            ]
        }
        disney {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId 'com.cc.whitelabel.disney'
        }
        pogo {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId 'com.cc.whitelabel.pogo'
        }
        dev {
            dimension "server"
        }
        staging {
            dimension "server"
        }
        production {
            dimension "server"
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the Android WhiteLabeling/App Branding/ProductFalvours, Here I share my build.gradle for creating app branding. the gradle file syntax may vary based on the version of IDE.

> Tools:
>
> Android Studio IDE:3.1
>
> Target Version:27

AppModule ***build.gradle***

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appmohan"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // APK signing configuration
    android.signingConfigs {
        MobileApp { }
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"
    productFlavors {
        cartoon {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.appmohan.cartoon"
            versionName '1.0.1'
            versionCode 2
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26
        }
        disney {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.appmohan.disney"
            versionName "1.0.1"
            versionCode 2
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26
        }
        pogo {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.appmohan.pogo"
            versionName "1.0.1"
            versionCode 2
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 26
        }
    }


    android.buildTypes {
        debug {
            //do our url stuff
        }
        stagging {
            //do our url stuff
        }
        release {
            //do our url stuff
        }
    }

    sourceSets.cartoon{
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'src/cartoon/res']
    }
    sourceSets.disney{
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'src/disney/res']
    }
    sourceSets.pogo{
        res.srcDirs = ['res', 'src/pogo/res']
    }
}
```

For experimental and education purpose I created this app.
[GitHub Link AndroidWhiteLabel/App Branding/ProductFalvour](https://github.com/mohanrajsambath/AndroidWhiteLabel/wiki/) 
Thanks to Android Studio to achieve the result.And thanks to all my referral authors.

Happy Coding:)